# Dealing with no default constructor in custom allocators

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory, memory-management, constructor

I have a #define to my `new` macro, to use my own allocator, such as `MYNEW(Type, Allocator)` where I will go and allocate some raw memory using `malloc`, then later use placement new to allocate the type on the raw memory such as

```
#define MYNEW(Type, Allocator) Allocator->Alloc<Type>(sizeof(Type));`
template<typename Type>
Type* Alloc(unsigned int size) // Allocator::Alloc<Type>
{
    return (Type*)new(malloc(reportedSize)) Type;
}
```

However, I am running into issues when there is no default constructor for `Type`. One scenario I tried was doing something such as `MYNEW_1(Type, Allocator, ConVar1)` where ConVar1 would be passed such as

```
#define MYNEW_1(Type, Allocator, ConVar1) Allocator->Alloc<Type>(sizeof(Type), ConVar1);`
template<typename Type, typename ConVarType>
Type* Alloc(unsigned int size, ConVarType Convar1) // Allocator::Alloc<Type>
{
    return (Type*)new(malloc(reportedSize)) Type(Convar1);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that for my custom Vector, I am also using MYNEW to allocation memory. However, for some `Type`'s used for my Vector, there is no default constructor and I can't tell how many variables the constructor may require.

Does anyone have any insight into how this problem could be solved? (Without of course saying using std:: types instead of my own. I am doing this to learn more). I do not wish to just overload `operator new` as I have memory tracking in there as I do not wish to have the memory tracked twice (there is more internal tracking to `Alloc`, but what I have shown is the simplified example) and would rather just use malloc.

Comment: Variadic templates might be a solution

Comment: You need not justify your approach, of course, especially if you are just learning; but for curiosity's sake, would you care to comment on why you wish to avoid defining a default constructor?

Comment: @thb: Some classes I am using do not have a default constructor and have only constructors that do not have default parameters.

Comment: What's the `Allocator`? Looks like a struct that has a `Alloc` method, but `Alloc` here is a free function. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Paranaix: I would be interesting in knowing how variadic templates could solve this problem. I have read about them in the past and I don't think my compiler has full support for them at the moment though. Also, I am sure this problem exists before the use of variadic templates so I assume there is another way to solve this.

Comment: @Lorenzo Pistone: I modified the question to show that Alloc is Allocator::Alloc (Allocator is a class, Alloc is a function on the class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you're not only doing your own custom allocator, but that you're also not necessarily trying to define an STL-compatible allocator.  However, I think it's useful to recognize that for all their faults, STL allocators were designed to handle this case.  [Allocation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/allocate/) is separate from [construction](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/construct/):

> Notice that [`allocator::construct`] does not allocate space for the element, it should already be available at `p` (see member `allocate` to allocate space).
>
> It is equivalent to [call to placement `new` that copies an existing object].

Generally speaking, I believe you have two options:  either (1) overload `operator new` to handle allocating memory and let the system handle the construction, or (2) make your allocator interface more like the STL allocator interface.

---

"Overloading `operator new`" is often used to mean two things:  (1) replacing it, or (2) adding a new version of `new`.  When I originally answered, I was using the first meaning (which really should be called "replacing `operator new`" or "overriding `operator new`"); but thinking more about this, I've determined that truly overloading `operator new` would meet your requirements.

I should mention that the syntax to call an overloaded `operator delete` is so bad that many people avoid this technique for that reason alone.  Instead of overloading `delete`, you can create a function (say, `deallocate`) and use it.

The value of this approach is that you follow the language standard of separating memory allocation from object construction, and you leave it up to the compiler to take care of the object construction for you.  You don't have to worry about forwarding operators, or about classes without default constructors, or any of those issues.

Overloading `operator new`/`operator delete` (of course, I'm relying on you to flesh out `track` and `release`):

```
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Allocator {
    void track(void* p, const void* container) const;
    void release(void* p, const void* container) const;
};

void* operator new (size_t size, const Allocator& alloc, const void* container)
{
    void* allocated_memory = std::malloc(size);
    if (!allocated_memory) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    alloc.track(allocated_memory, container);
    return allocated_memory;
}

void operator delete(void* p, const Allocator& alloc, const void* container)
{
    alloc.release(p, container);
    std::free(p);
}

int main()
{
    Allocator alloc;
    int* i = new (alloc, NULL) int;
    operator delete(i, alloc, NULL);
}
```

Overloading `operator new` and using a function `deallocate`:

```
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Allocator {
    void track(void* p, const void* container) const;
    void release(void* p, const void* container) const;
};

void* operator new (size_t size, const Allocator& alloc, const void* container)
{
    void* allocated_memory = std::malloc(size);
    if (!allocated_memory) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    alloc.track(allocated_memory, container);
    return allocated_memory;
}

template<typename T> void deallocate(T* p, const Allocator& alloc, const void* container)
{
    p->~T();
    alloc.release(p, container);
    std::free(p);
}

int main()
{
    Allocator alloc;
    int* i = new (alloc, NULL) int;
    deallocate(i, alloc, NULL);
}
```

---

One case that you should consider is what to do when `new` succeeds but constructing the object fails.  That is, when there's plenty of memory, but some other reason that the object can't be created.  The system is actually smart enough to call the right `delete` (well, the `delete` that has a signature that the system thinks it should have) to release the allocated memory; but only if there is a `delete` with that signature.  You may well want to overload `operator delete` **and** provide a `deallocate` function, with one of them being defined in terms of the other:

```
void operator delete(void* p, const Allocator& alloc, const void* container)
{
    alloc.release(p, container);
    std::free(p);
}

template<typename T> void deallocate(T* p, const Allocator& alloc, const void* container)
{
    p->~T();
    operator delete(p, alloc, container);
}
```

Comment: I am indeed trying to do both in the same function. Perhaps it was just being naive, but I did not see the purpose for my own allocation methods to have both Allocation and construction separate, my MYNEW macro would always be the interface for allocating/constructing. As I mentioned, I did not want to overload operator new. Given the code I provided would you be able to show how I could "make your allocator interface more like the STL allocator interface.".

Comment: @chadb: It's both a question of what your `Allocator` class does and how it's used (how your `Vector` class uses it).  Essentially, your `Vector` class must always (1) construct an object, then (2) pass that constructed object to `Allocator::construct` to get it a copy of it placed in the relevant memory block.  I'm sure the new Standard has provisions for moving the copy into the memory block, but I'm not up to speed on what those provisions would be.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution with variadic templates and macros.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MYNEW(Allocator, ...) (Allocator)->Alloc(__VA_ARGS__);

template<typename Type>
struct Allocator{
    template<typename... Args>
    Type* Alloc(Args... args){
        cout<<"weird allocator"<<endl;
        return new(malloc(sizeof(Type))) Type(args...);
    }
};

struct test{
    test(int a, bool b, const char* c){
        cout<<"test constructor with a="<<a<<", b="<<b<<", c="<<c<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Allocator<test> myallocator;
    test* obj=MYNEW(&myallocator, 3, true, "hello");
}
```

Personally, I don't think that there's a clean solution (read, that doesn't require you to explicitly write what the `Allocator` would do, in the place where you're allocating the object) without variadic stuff.

You could also have a look at passing additional parameters (other that the pointer to the memory) to the new operator overload ([yes it is possible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)).

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. I have not used variadic templates in the past, only read about them. Is there much of a performance hit here by using them?

Comment: @chadb, compilation times might be longer, but since they "synthesize" functions for you, then at runtime there should be no performance impact. Also, read my edit about the additional parameters that you can pass in the new operator overload.